# When using Xcode5, how do I decide how the app will look? iOS7 or iOS6 style

Tags: ios6, xcode4, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5

I have some apps developed using Xcode4.
When opening the projects and build them for the 5 simulator using Xcode5, most of the apps will look iOS7 style when built for 5 simulator while some still looks iOS6 no matter what I do 
The apps are pretty much the same so I do not understand how to decide myself which style it is going to be.
Looking at the settings I do not see any difference.
The app which is built as a iOS6 like style seems not possible to change to iOS7 style, and some apps are built as iOS7 style as default and is not possible to change to iOS6 style using Xcode5.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends, most of the standard UI elements are redesigned in iOS7 (UIAlertView for instance), you can't do a lot, if you want to keep the ioS6 look you should rebuild all these components by yourself.
Elements that adhere to the appearance proxy can be customized to look like pre-iOS7, but it will be a hard job.
In iOS7 you also have another "problem" to manage, by default all views are full-screen, this is simply to solve if you deploy only on iOS7, bit harder if you deploy for prior iOS7 and iOS7.
There i a way around... download the 4.6 version of xcode ance deploy only on iOS6, most of the UI elements will maintain the same aspect, it seems that Apple still accept <=iOS6 binaries.

Comment: Yes I know that iOS6 binaries are accepted. I have updated several since release of iOS7. But I do not understand the behavior of Xcode5 when two very alike apps are differently treated by Xcode5. One is only iOS6 style and one is only iOS7 style no matter what I do.

Comment: It's easy, the app takes the look of the operative system is running it. If you want to customize, you should use appearance proxy for elements that support it, and for other you must start for scratch. There is no secret options or whatever.

Comment: Thats is not the fact for one app I have. It refuses to look like iOS7 style if I build it with Xcode5 and run it on Simulator 5 iOS7. Still looks exactly as iOS6 style. Other apps I build the same way adapts to iOS7 look. I do not understand why that app particularly refuses.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It is like you say. And that is what I thought it should be. Thats why I was so confused. After restarting the simulator it suddenly was iOS7 style to that app. The simulator seems to somehow remember the previous build which was done from Xcode4. Even if I had two versions at the same display (with different name).